# How can I import a CSV file in python?

Tags: pandas, numpy, csv, typeerror, python-import

I'm trying to read from a CSV file using the pandas library in python (using spyder (Python 3.7)), But I am getting an error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "<ipython-input-104-744f03c12bee>", line 1, in 
>       datasets = pd.read_csv('Data.csv')
>
> File
>   "\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py",
>   line 702, in parser_f
>       return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
>
> File
>   "\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py",
>   line 435, in _read
>       data = parser.read(nrows)
>
> File
>   "\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py",
>   line 1154, in read
>       df = DataFrame(col_dict, columns=columns, index=index)
>
> File
>   "\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py",
>   line 392, in **init**
>       mgr = init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
>
> File
>   "\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py",
>   line 212, in init_dict
>       return arrays_to_mgr(arrays, data_names, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
>
> File
>   "\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py",
>   line 56, in arrays_to_mgr
>       arrays = _homogenize(arrays, index, dtype)
>
> File
>   "\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py",
>   line 277, in _homogenize
>       raise_cast_failure=False)
>
> File
>   "\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py",
>   line 582, in sanitize_array
>       subarr = _try_cast(data, True, dtype, copy, raise_cast_failure)
>
> File
>   "\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py",
>   line 720, in _try_cast
>       subarr = np.array(arr, dtype=object, copy=copy)
>
> TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

I have imported the numpy library as np, as well as the pandas library as pd; the working directory has been set correctly to the same as the file save location.

```
import pandas as pd
datasets = pd.read_csv('Data.csv')
```

Following is the data that I am currently working on:
[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfeWJ.png)

Comment: can you provide bits of your csv ? Did you try this exact code without anything else and it still fails ? I not, we need more information.

Comment: your csv seems to be tab or space delimited, try using the `sep` parameter, e.g.: `pd.read_csv('Data.csv', sep=' ')`

Comment: The call looks right - for common csv files and pandas setup.  So what's different in your case?  A sample of the file might help.  Traceback of the error might help.  If you want help you need to provide more information.  Otherwise we'll be guessing.

Comment: Whenever you report a Python error, include the *complete* traceback (i.e. the complete error message) in the question.  There is useful information in there.

Comment: @Derlin, I have added the data in the question, I tried using other CSV files as well was make a new CSV file. Both times I got the same error. One file having 1 row was read sucessfully, others failed. I also tried using the `sep` parameter, it stil gave me the same error. Thank you!

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I have added the complete traceback, thank you!

Comment: @hpaulj, I have added the data as well as the traceback, Thank you!

Comment: Add the csv as text, please, not as image. Is it a text file? Or excel? `read_csv` needs to read a text file. If the separator field are spaces, try `pd.read_csv('Data.csv', sep=' \s+')`.

Comment: Try it again, in a new `ipython` session.  I don't think this problem is with the `csv`.  Rather something has messed up the `np` or `np.array` definition.

Comment: @hpaulj, thank you, making a new session and directory for the same worked, Thank you everyone for the answers and time!

Answer (score 0):

Actually your file(data.csv) is not a csv file. Its in PNG format. So, you can use PIL module in python.

```
from PIL import Image

imframe = Image.open('data.csv')
imframe
```